# How to run the thread groups consecutively and then start again the same cycle again in jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter

How to run the thread groups consecutively say thread group 1, then 2, then 3 till Thread Group 'N', after that it should again repeat the same cycle thread group 1, thread group 2 and so on for 100 times in JMeter.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of the following possible options:

1. Run the whole JMeter test for 100 times using your operating system scripting mechanisms (Windows [batch files](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/index.htm) or Linux [shell scripts](https://www.shellscript.sh/))
2. Schedule the test execution using built-in operating system mechanisms like [Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) for Windows or [cron](https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux) for Linux
3. Use a 3rd-party orchestration software, i.e. [Continuous Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) server like [Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/continuous-integration-101-how-run-jmeter-jenkins/)